# Is there any app for windows 10 to monitor in real-time how much power is being consumed?

Tags: windows-10, power-management

Looking for something to replace Microsoft's Joulemeter*, which isn't available anymore - preferably free & works on windows 10

What it did that I am looking for is display in real-time how many watts my computer is using at any given second (and then go into more details as far as specific programs) - likely based on power levels of CPU/GPU vs battery drain, etc. 
I am not super sure how it worked at a very detailed level nor how percise it is/was, but I am looking for that ballpark value & real-time functionality

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what else I can use today instead of it?

*I am fine with Joulemeter's limitations, i.e. only works on laptops/notebooks/etc. - but if someone has something that works better / is more general purpose that's great

Comment: There are hardware based sensors you could use from wall to pc (in the middle) to give you accurate totals. Doesn’t break own apps etc though.

Comment: @ThisIsNotMyRealName those don't work so well for laptops with batteries, they end up measuring the charger / battery state of charge instead most of the time, and inserting it between the computer and it's battery is tricky at best in most cases